# ClassNotFoundException on Github class - jcabi library

Tags: java, api, github, netbeans, classnotfoundexception

I'am using NetBeans to write a java application that would allow me to get the zip file of a GitHub user repository. In order to do that, I imported an external jar library, [jcabi library](http://github.jcabi.com/), into the netbeans project that let me communicate with the GitHub API.

**How I imported**: right-click on the project -> properties -> libraries -> Add JAR/Folder

**Then I start coding**: I tried different constructors for the Github class (the root for communicating with the whole library), but always the same error.

[image]

I also tried with another .jar library: [kohsuke](http://github-api.kohsuke.org/) -> same error.

And if it is not enought, I also tried with eclipse -> same error.

Now, I don't know what the problem could be:

- Library importation? (When I write The Github class, netbeans shows me the possibility to import the class, so I don't think this could be the problem, but still...)
- My usage of the Github constructor (Probably)
- something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure you download this jar file: jcabi-github-0.23-jar-with-dependencies.jar. It has all the dependencies you need. [Which can be found here towards the end of the page.](http://github.jcabi.com/)

> It is strongly recommended to use RetryWire to avoid accidental I/O exceptions:

This compiled for me:

```
 Github github = new RtGithub(
 new RtGithub()
 .entry()
 .through(RetryWire.class)
);
```

**Sample program:**

```
 Github github = new RtGithub(
                 new RtGithub("yourUsername", "yourPassword")
                 .entry()
                 .through(RetryWire.class)
 );

 Repo repo = github.repos().get(
 new Coordinates.Simple("sebenalern/database_project"));
 Issues issues = repo.issues();
 Issue issue = issues.create("issue title", "issue body");
 issue.comments().post("issue comment");
```

After running the above code it posted an issue in my repo with title as "issue title" the body as "issue body" and a comment as "issue comment"

Hope this helps! Let me know if you need anything clarified or more examples.
**Note this code was tested.**